# What is fix-it-all.sh and how to run it?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

(I am following these steps to install a simulator in ubuntu but cant go ahead of point no. 6)

Steps to get disksim with dixtrac working for a 64bit machine with the SSD patch from Microsoft:

1) Download Disksim-4.0-with-dixtrac for x86_64 from the CMU website

2) Download the SSD drive addon from Microsoft research

3) Extract both tarballs

4) Copy the folder ssdmodel from the ssd addon into the root directory of disksim-4.0

5) Copy this folder (64bit-ssd-patches) into the root directory of disksim-4.0

6) In this folder make sure your shell is bash or a derivative and run fix-it-all.sh

7) Rejoice!

8) Type make at the root of disksim-4.0

9) Validate everything built properly via the runvalid scripts in /valid and ssdmodel/valid

10) Done and done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `cd` in the directory of the file you want to run.

If the `fix-it-all.sh` file is executable you can execute it with:

```
$ ./fix-it-all.sh
```

If the file is **not** executable you can run it by using bash:

```
$ bash fix-it-all.sh
```

Comment: Thank you. But it says 'no such file or directory'.

Comment: You have to be in extracted folder, where the file exists.

Comment: And in step 7) do i just have to be happy or really have to do something with it? :) @Samuel Philipp

Comment: No, I don't think you have to something. Was step 6 successful?

Comment: Thank you.. yes the commands you suggested did work for step 6.

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem. Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you.

Comment: Done with it :)